# My lstm output looks too 'linear' what's the problem?

Tags: lstm, prediction

i build a LSTM network using keras in order to predict stock price.When the model predicts the testing set,the answer looks good,but when i want to predict the future data,the answewr seems a little bit too 'linear',what can be the problem?Is the method I process my data wrong?or it is because of the model?[image]
I tried folloing code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout,BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed,RepeatVector
lookback = 30
def train_data(dataset,lookback):
    test = dataset[len(dataset)*9//10:]
    train = dataset[:len(dataset)-len(test)]

    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    X_test = []
    train_open = train['Open']
    
    train_open = train_open.values.reshape(-1,1)
    train_open = sc.fit_transform(train_open)
    for i in range(lookback,len(train_open)):
        X_train.append(train_open[i-lookback:i-1,0])
        y_train.append(train_open[i,0])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
    X_train = np.reshape(X_train,
                            (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    

    test_set = dataset[len(dataset)-len(test)-lookback:]['Open'].values
    test_set = test_set.reshape(-1,1)
    test_set = sc.transform(test_set)
    for i in range(lookback ,len(test_set)):
        X_test.append(test_set[i-lookback:i-1,0])
    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

    return X_train,y_train , X_test ,test['Open'].values,test_set
def shuffle(X,Y):
  np.random.seed(10)
  randomList = np.arange(X.shape[0])
  np.random.shuffle(randomList)
  return X[randomList], Y[randomList]
def build_model(X_train):
    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(LSTM(units = 10,activation='relu',input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dense(1))

    regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_absolute_error')
    history = regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 25, batch_size = 8)
    regressor.save('lstm')
    plt.title('train_loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.plot( history.history["loss"])
    plt.show()
    return regressor

def forecast(regressor,inputs,predicted_stock_price,num_days):
    predict_list = inputs[-lookback:]
    for i in range(num_days):
        x = predict_list[-lookback:]
        #print(x)
        x= np.array(x)
        x = np.reshape(x, (1,lookback,1))
        print(x)
        out = regressor.predict(x)[0][0]
        print(out)
        out = np.array([[out]])

        predict_list = np.append(predict_list,out,axis = 0)
    
    print(predict_list)
    predict_list = sc.inverse_transform(predict_list)
    predicted_stock_price = np.append(predicted_stock_price,predict_list[-num_days:],axis =0)
    return predicted_stock_price

sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
data = pd.read_csv("NFLX.csv")
X_train ,y_train ,X_test , y_test,inputs= train_data(data,lookback) 
print(X_test)
X_train,y_train = shuffle(X_train,y_train)

regressor = build_model(X_train)
#regressor = keras.models.load_model('lstm/')
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)
#print(predicted_stock_price)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
predicted_stock_price = forecast(regressor,inputs,predicted_stock_price,50)

plt.plot(predicted_stock_price[2:], color = 'green', label = 'Predicted  Stock Price')
plt.plot(y_test, color = 'black', label = 'Real Stock Price')

plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```